# General topology: if $A \subset B$ and $B$ is closed then $\partial A \subset B$

Tags: general-topology

I am not quite sure how to go about proving this, will you please provide some guidance? I want to show that if $A\subset B$ and $B$ is closed,then $\partial A \subset B$.

Comment: This is not complex analysis. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since $B$ is closed, $B=\overline{B}$. Hence 
$$
\partial A \subset \overline A \subset \overline B = B.
$$

Comment: quick question, how do we know that A(bar)⊂B(bar). Isn't that essentially what we are trying to prove?

Comment: Suppose $x \in X \setminus \overline{B}$. Then there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ which does not intersect $B$, hence it cannot intersect $A$. Therefore, $x \in X \setminus \overline{A}$.